# Generic class method calls

Tags: java, generics

I apologize in advanced for my lack of knowledge in generics... I am trying to understand how generics work and I am not sure what it is but I am missing a key part that is eluding me so hopefully someone can clarify a little more and get me over this hump.

```
BaseDtoUtil.mapToDto(map, OcrImageDocDto.class); //OcrImageDocDto extends DtoUtils

//This method is in class BaseDtoUtil
public static <T> List<T> mapToDto(Map<String, Object> map, Class<? extends DtoUtils> klass) throws SparkSQLException{
      T obj = (T)klass.newInstance();
      //return a list of these
}
```

So I guess there are two questions I have:

1. First is why does it complain when I pass in `OcrImageDocDto.class` when the variable defined for the method call is any class? (I originally had it as (`Class<?>`) Doesn't that mean any class value? Obviously I am wrong but not sure what it means then.
2. Second question is if I send in a class value am I actually able to get that instance and return a type value back? `<T> List<T>`? If I am not mistaken I believe that the generic variables `<T> List<T>` is used for instantiations of the object. But what do they do if it is a static method?

I am a bit lost and maybe the way I understand generics is wrong... So if someone can clear these two up I think it will help a lot!

Comment: You would need to use `<T extends DtoUtils>` instead of just `<T>`, and `Class<? extends T>`.

Comment: Also of interest: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: consider changing the signature to `public static <T extends DtoUtils> List<T> mapToDto(Map<String, Object> map, Class<T> klass)`--to let the method know `List` of which type it should return.

Comment: "But what do they do if it is a static method?" I don't follow what you mean here - the static-ness isn't relevant to the generics or what can be returned.

Comment: @Sasha this makes perfect sense now. Thanks for your input! This helped a lot!
Andy and Christophe Thanks for the input. Helps push me in the right direction too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

```
public static <T> List<T> mapToDto(
    Map<String, Object> map,
    Class<? extends DtoUtils> klass) throws SparkSQLException{
  T obj = (T)klass.newInstance();
  ...
```

You don't know that `klass.newInstance()` can be cast to a `T` - all you know is that it is an instance of `DtoUtils` (or a subclass).

As such, you can either change to use:

```
DtoUtils obj = klass.newInstance();
```

or constrain `T` to extend `DtoUtils`:

```
public static <T extends DtoUtils> List<T> mapToDto(
    Map<String, Object> map,
    Class<? extends T> klass) throws SparkSQLException{
  T obj = klass.newInstance();
  ...
```

Question 2:

Yes, because you have an actual instance of the class. You would not be able to create an instance without that (or some other object which can provide instances of `T`), because of type erasure.

This would not work:

```
public static <T extends DtoUtils> List<T> mapToDto(
    Map<String, Object> map) throws SparkSQLException{
  T obj = new T();  // Compiler error.
```

Something like the following works just fine:

```
T obj = klass.newInstance();
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj);
return list;
```

Comment: Ahhhh I love answer 1. That makes a lot of sense. Also can you explain how it knows what T is? is it based on what we are setting on the opposite side of the "=" or how does it know how to resolve what the T value is?

Comment: I am understanding it now. I see that it is what the object is set to to determine T. Also I like the comment that is higher up on how to call this method......
public static <T extends DtoUtils> T mapToDto(Map<String, Object> map, Class<T> klass) throws SparkSQLException;

This allows me to force them to pass in the same value that I am setting it to. Andy can you please change the Class<? extends T> and change it to Class<T> and I will mark this as the answer! Thanks!!

Comment: `T` is never really determined. It is just known to be something which extends `DtoUtils`, so we know that we can invoke any of the `DtoUtils` methods on instances of it.

Comment: Hmm then the question is why does it compile? OcrImageDocsDto extends DtoUtils..... What this method states is that OcrImageDocsDto extends OcrImageDocsDto which it does not.

Comment: Yes it does: `extends` doesn't mean "is a subclass of" in generic bounds: it means "is the same as or is a subclass of". See [JLS sec 4.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1).

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I did not know that lol. Well then thanks for the information!!